# What is a "subscheme"?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, definition

Every source I've looked at defines *open subschemes* and *closed subschemes*, but the definitions always look ad-hoc and not closely related to one another.  Are there other kinds of subschemes?  If not, can we give a definition for a "subscheme" and then deduce that the only ones that exist are open and closed subschemes?

For instance, EGA I, Definition 4.1.3, says (roughly):

> We say a ringed space $(Y, \mathcal{O}_Y)$ is a subprescheme of a prescheme $(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$ if:
>
> 1. $Y$ is a locally closed subset of $X$, and
> 2. If $U$ denotes the largest open set of $X$ containing $Y$ and such that $X$ is closed in $U$, then $(Y, \mathcal{O}_Y)$ is a subprescheme of $(U, \mathcal{O}_X|_U)$ defined by a quasicoherent sheaf of ideals of $\mathcal{O}_X|_U$.

Is there some way to characterize this in terms of morphisms without having to build in the locally closed condition from the beginning?

Comment: The first thing to try might be "monomorphism in the category of schemes" but I expect that this definition behaves poorly because the corresponding notion of epimorphism in the category of rings behaves poorly. Maybe a regular monomorphism? (This might only produce closed subschemes.)

Comment: To be short, a subscheme is a closed subscheme of an open subscheme.

Comment: @Cantlog: Yes, that's what the definition I included in my question says.  But *why*?  What motivates this seemingly arbitrary definition?

Comment: Open subschemes and closed subschemes are both reasonable (if different) things, and it is reasonable enough to combine two reasonable notions. Open subschemes are in some sense "maximal" with respect to the underlying subspace. Closed subschemes are defined by equations.

Comment: @ZhenLin: Yes, but that's not a very satisfying definition.  If I said something like "Permutation groups are reasonable, and cyclic groups are reasonable.  Let's define a *group* to be either a permutation group or a cyclic group." then I think you'll agree most people wouldn't be satisfied with such a definition.

Comment: A "subscheme" should be, in some appropriate sense, a subspace which is also a scheme in its own right.  This is how sub-X is defined for every other X I've ever seen.

Comment: Not at all. Think about it carefully: (the boundary of) the square is not a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$, even though it is a subspace and can be endowed with a smooth structure. The important point is that a submanifold must _inherit_ the smooth structure. And also, the map $t \mapsto (t^2, t^3)$ is injective and is a homeomorphism onto its image but not a smooth embedding. These delicate subtleties are simply more obvious and more difficult to work around when working with schemes.

Comment: I certainly didn't mean to imply that I thought a "subscheme" of $X$ ought to be any scheme homeomorphic to a subset of $X$, any more than I think a subgroup of $G$ is any group of the same cardinality as some subset of $G$.  But it seems there ought to be some abstract characterizations of subschemes in terms of inclusion maps, rather than a characterization that explicitly forces us to build things in two steps by defining open subschemes and closed subschemes separately.

Comment: The intelligent and courteous discussion between Daniel and @Zhen sets a standard of behaviour on this site. Kudos to both of them.

Comment: @DanielMcLaury You could define subscheme to mean "scheme equipped with a morphism that is injective on points" if you like, but then that would imply that, say, $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{C}$ is a "subscheme" of $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{Q}$. So one has to impose some condition on the structure sheaf. But what condition? In $\mathbf{CRing}$, about the only property that quotients $A \to A / I$ and localisations $A \to A [S^{-1}]$ share is that they are epimorphisms, and epimorphisms in $\mathbf{CRing}$ are [notoriously tricky](http://mathoverflow.net/q/109/11640).

Comment: A more general notion of immersions $f : X\to Y$ of schemes could be a morphism of schemes such that $f$ is a homeomorphism from $X$ to the subspace $f(X)$ of $Y$, and $O_{Y,f(x)}\to O_{X,x}$ is surjective for all $x\in X$. Call such morphisms $R$-immersions. Then the immersions defined in EGA are those $R$-immersions which are locally of finite type.

Comment: @Cantlog: that's exactly the sort of definition I was looking for.  I'd be happy to take the preceding comment as an answer.

Comment: @Qiaochu: For (regular) monomorphisms of schemes, see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/66279 and http://mathoverflow.net/questions/56591 . In fact, there are (too) many of them.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think a reasonable definition of an immersion of ringed topological spaces $f : X\to Y$ is :

1. $f$ induces a homeomorphism $X\to f(X)$;
2. For any $x\in X$, the canonical homomorphism $O_{Y, f(x)}\to O_{X,x}$ is surjective.

In the category of schemes, this implies that $f$ is a monomorphism (see http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01L6). Let us call such morphisms of schemes *R-immersions* (R for ringed topological spaces). Immersions of schemes in the standard sense (EGA, stacks project) are R-immersions.

**Fact 1.** If $X, Y$ are algebraic varieties over field $k$ (schemes of finite type over $k$), then any R-immersion $f: X\to Y$ is actually an immersion.

**Fact 2.** More generally, an R-immersion $f :X\to Y$ is an immersion if and only if $f$ is locally of finite type.

Now why immersions are prefered to R-immersions ? I don't really know. Fact 1 above could be an explanation. One question I don't know the answer is whether R-immersions are stable by base change (this is the case for immersions).  If the answer is no, then this is one more reason to prefer immersions to R-immersions.

Example of an R-immersion which is not an immersion. Let $X$ be a scheme and let $x\in X$. Then the canonical morphism $i_x: \mathrm{Spec}(O_{X,x})\to X$ is an $R$-immersion. However, if e.g. $X$ is an *infinite* integral scheme, and if $\xi$ is its generic point, then $i_\xi$ is not an immersion because $\{ \xi\}$ is not locally closed in $X$.

**Edit: afterthought.**

The initial question can be interpreted as follows: given a subset $X$ in a scheme $(Y, O_Y)$, is it possible to endow $X$ with the structure of a scheme $(X, O_X)$, the latter being related in some manner to $(Y, O_Y)$ ? A first natural requirement is the underlying topological space of $X$ is given the induced topology, this is Condition (1) in my tentative definition of $R$-immersion. For the sheaf of regular functions, it is also natural to ask that the regular functions on $X$ are "induced" by regular functions on $Y$ and my Condition (2) is a natural candidate.

Then it turns out that the answer is positive for locally closed subsets of $Y$. I don't see other natural category of subsets for which the answer is positive. Anyway it seems hard to characterize subsets of $Y$ for which the answer is positive. A necessary condition is being pro-constructible (roughly speaking, possibly infinite intersection of constructible subsets), but even constructible is not enough to a get the structure of subscheme in the sense of $R$-immersion (one can show this for the classical example of constructible but  non-locally closed subset of the affine plane: remove the $x$-axe and add the origin back).

Comment: Very good post, Cantlog. Indeed I have heard a  mathematician I admire wonder why the canonical morphism $i_x: \mathrm{Spec}(O_{X,x})\to X$ is not considered an immersion.

Comment: R-immersions are stable under base change. [But I'm too lazy to write down the proof, its quite long.]

Comment: Fact 3: An R-immersion is an immersion iff $f(X) \subseteq Y$ is a locally closed subset.

Answer (score 2):

I think that there is no abstract nonsense answer. Locally closed immersions just arise naturally when one wants to study algebraic varieties. The local model looks as follows: We work in affine $n$-space $\mathbb{A}^n_k$ and consider not just closed subsets $\{x \in \mathbb{A}^n_k : p_1(x)=\dotsc=p_r(x) = 0\}$, but also allow inequalities by considering $\{x \in \mathbb{A}^n_k : p_1(x)=\dotsc=p_r(x) = 0 , f_1(x) \neq 0, \dotsc,f_s(x) \neq 0\}$. This is again an affine variety with coordinate ring $\{f_1,\dotsc,f_s\}^{-1} k[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]/(p_1,\dotsc,p_n)$. More generally, if $X$ is any scheme and $Z$ is a locally closed subset of the underlying set of $X$, then one may endow $Z$ with a scheme structure and the inclusion $Z \to X$ becomes a monomorphism of schemes. Of course one might try to characterize all those subsets with this property. Examples are infinite intersections of open affine schemes. Or one may try to characterize monomorphisms of schemes, see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/56591/what-are-the-monomorphisms-in-the-category-of-schemes) for some information.

Comment: This also looks relevant: http://users.mat.unimi.it/users/vezzani/Files/Research/open_immersions.pdf