# For which smooth maps $f:X\to Y$ is the restriction $C^\infty_{Y,fx}\to C^\infty_{X,x}$ surjective?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/817832/223002), the notion of $R$-immersion of ringed spaces was suggested. It means a topological embedding $f:X\to Y$ such that germ restriction on the structure sheaves is surjective. $$\mathcal O_{Y,fx}\twoheadrightarrow \mathcal O_{X,x}$$

I am trying to understand what this condition might mean for smooth manifolds. In this case the structure sheaves are the sheaves of smooth real functions. Let $f:X\to Y$ a smooth map. Precomposing with it induces a restriction map on germs $$C^\infty_{Y,fx}\to C^\infty_{X,x}.$$

**Question 1.** Surjectivity means a smooth germ on $X$ extends along $f$ to a smooth germ on $Y$? 
When does this hold? I don't see why it should hold for smooth immersions, for instance. (Or for smooth embeddings.)

<s>**Question 2.** Suppose that instead of the sheaves $C^\infty$ we consider the tangent sheaves, i.e the sheaves of sections of the tangent bundles. When do we have surjectivity of germ restriction $$T_{Y,fx}\to T_{X,x}?$$ (This seems closer to smooth immersions.)</s>

Comment: With local charts you are looking at the ring $R_n$ of germs of smooth functions around $0 \in \Bbb{R}^n$ and a smooth map $F:\Bbb{R}^n\to \Bbb{R}^m, F(0) = 0$, iff its jacobian at $0$ has rank $n$ (that is $F$ is locally injective) then $u(y) \mapsto u(f(x))$ is surjective $R_m \to R_n$. On the other hand if $F$ is surjective then there is a sub vector-space $V \subset \Bbb{R}^n$ such that $F|_V$ is locally bijective, so there is $G$ smooth such that $G \circ F|_V(v) = v$ for $v \in V,|v| < r$ and $u(x)\to u(G(y))$ is surjective $R_n \to R_m$. Those local maps extend to simply connected sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For question 1:

Note that if $\phi$ is a germ at $f(x)$, then $f^*\phi$ is a germ at $x$, and its differential at $x$ is $d_{f(x)}\phi \circ d_x f$. Thus for any $\phi$, the differential at $x$ of $f^*\phi$ must vanish on the kernel of $d_x f$.

So, if $f^*$ is surjective, $f$ must be an immersion at $x$.

Conversely, a well-known theorem states that if $f$ is immersive at $x$, then there are smooth coordinates around $x$ and $f(x)$ such that $f(y_1, \ldots, y_r)=(y_1, \ldots, y_r, 0, \ldots, 0)$. As a consequence, there exists a smooth $\pi : U \subset Y \rightarrow X$, defined on a neighborhood of $f(x)$, such that $\pi \circ f=Id$.

As a consequence, if $\phi$ is a germ around $x$, $\phi \circ \pi$ is a germ around $f(x)$ and $f^* \phi \circ \pi=\phi$, thus $f^*$ is surjective.

I am not sure about your second question, because I don’t understand what exactly your spaces are, and what your pull-back operator is.

Comment: Dear @Mindlack, thanks for your very lucid answer! I should have thought a bit harder and used the local structure of immersions. Regarding my second question, I have again failed to think things through. There is no pullback of vector fields along an arbitrary smooth map.

Comment: Dear @Mindlack, I want to make sure I understand the implication "So, if $f^\ast$ is surjective, $f$ must be an immersion at $x$." As you've explained, $\ker \mathrm T_xf^\ast \varphi \supset \ker \mathrm T_xf$. If $f^\ast $ is surjective, we have $\ker \mathrm T_x \psi\supset \ker \mathrm T_xf$ for any real germ $\psi$ about $x$. Why does this imply $\ker \mathrm T_xf$ is trivial? Do you pass to coordinates and take for $\psi$ each of the projections?